# How paragraph numbers are read

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

I'd be glad if someone could tell me how numbers like "2.3.4.5.6" are read (pronounced)? "Two dot three dot four..." or "two three four" or maybe "two point three point four"?

Comment: It depends wholly on speaker and context, which vary by the phase of the moon and the solar wind. You cannot get a single right answer here.  You can get no more than a survey of what various people might say.

Comment: This has been asked before, but I can't locate the question. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: @tchrist so doest that mean I can read them whatever I want? :)

Comment: Related: [Name for number format used in "Section 3.2.1"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88047/name-for-number-format-used-in-section-3-2-1)

Comment: The two standard ways to read them are by saying _point_ or _dot_ for the (.), but not both. If you don't include one of those words & say only _two-three-four-five-six-etc._, you might confuse the listener.

Comment: @tchrist. That, certainly, but I think there's a more recent one.

Comment: @Barrie Probably [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59586/how-to-write-decimal-values-in-words). Also [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/how-do-you-correctly-say-large-numbers) or [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62397/reading-out-decimal-numbers-in-english). There may be others.

Comment: @tchrist. I know I answered one of them. Anyway, there should be enough here for the OP.

Comment: He's not asking for how to read decimal numbers. The context is different and I think the question is legit.

Comment: I am asking about case of paragraph or section headers, not decimal numbers.

Comment: Cross-link: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177286/when-to-use-point-vs-dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally accepted and correct pronunciation of 2.3.4.5.6 would be:

> Two point three point four point five point six.

The term *point* comes from *full point* as used as a punctuation mark or full stop. From Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> point, n.1
>
> a. A full stop (in full, full point);

Comment: And 2.13 as *two point thirteen*, not as the decimal number *two point one three*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, good point! Sorry couldn't resist.

Comment: @spiceyokooko Would you please point to a source?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't consensus on a single term to use.

In [another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196287/how-do-you-say-the-numbers-in-section-20-1234-in-a-government-regulation) here on StackExchange, Dan Sheppard writes:

> The word you use -- "dot", "point", "mark", "sub", -- is a matter of
>   personal taste or else institutional style, but when in doubt a word
>   which directly describes the symbol is usually fine (I would say point
>   here).

Version numbers carry a similar ambiguity. Both the terms "dot release" and "point release" are valid, and version numbers can be read in a variety of ways. In the case of "Web 2.0," for example, both "dot" and "point" [can be used](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2008/02/how_to_say_web_20.html):

> There seem to be many possible ways of saying this - "two point oh",
>   "two point zero", "two dot oh", two point nought", "two oh", "web two"
>   - with a certain amount of variation according to nationality, company loyalties and other factors.

Comment: In the specific case of version numbers, in my personal experience as a software engineer I also often hear the point omitted entirely — for example, reading version 1.2.3 as “one two three”. Given that software collaboration is so often remote and text-based, I wonder if there is regional variation in the spoken pronunciation.